# Remove Node Reference

Tags: nodes

in the upcoming weeks my client want me change some node reference options on his page.

I got 2 content types, press release and press office.
When they create a new press release, they are able to reference to a press office via the "References" Module.

Now they want me to remove some of the press offices and add some new. Thats not the problem,  when I remove the old press offices the old nodes lose their references as well. But they want  the old nodes keep their references, which sounds logical to me, but I've no idea how to do that.

Greetings from germany

sg

Comment: You could just unpublish the press office rather than delete it.

Comment: Unpublishing wont solve this, cause when I do this, the old nodes will lose there references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm clear, you don't actually want to remove any of the press offices because existing press releases should still be able to reference them, you just want to remove the option to associate new press releases with certain press offices (while at the same time, creating some new press offices that can be referenced).

So really, we just want to *filter* the list of press offices that can be referenced by new press releases.

I would suggest that you add a new boolean field to the press offices, something like: *"Can be referenced"*. Then create a view that filters press offices on that field. Finally, configure your Entity Reference field Mode to use *"Views: Filter by an entity reference view"* and select the view you just created.

Comment: That Sounds perfect, I'll give This a tty